# Sunrise and sunset time

Tags: javascript, time, openweathermap, weather-api

Hi i need help with my weather api in Javascript with Openweathermap API. I want it to display the time for the sunrise and the sunset of the searched city. Currently its just showing the unix time like for example: 1686799061. I want it to say the time in like 05:43 or something else. I hope yall can help me.
My code strips for the sunrise and sunset are the following:

How to fetch the time:

```
const { sunrise } = data.sys;
const { sunset } = data.sys;
```

showing:

```
document.querySelector(".sunrise").innerText = "Sonnenaufgang: " + sunrise;
document.querySelector(".sunset").innerText = "Sonnenuntergang: " + sunset;
```

I rly hope someone can help me with that!!!

I tried to do it with the
`.format('HH:mm a')`
which just causes my weather api to crash and not showing anything. I really need help with that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) allows you create a date/time per locale in a format of your choosing.

```js
// Mock data
const data = { sys: { sunrise: 1686819713693 } };

// Grab the sunrise timestamp
const { sunrise } = data.sys;

// Set the locale
const locale = 'en-GB';

function getFormattedTime(timestamp, locale) {
  
  // Create a date from the timestamp
  const date = new Date(timestamp);

  // Restrict the formatting to hour & minute
  const options = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };

  // Return appropriately formatted time
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options).format(date);

}

// Select the element
const sunriseEl = document.querySelector('.sunrise');

// Using a template string add the sunrise variable as
// text content to the element
sunriseEl.textContent = `Sonnenaufgang: ${getFormattedTime(sunrise, locale)}`;
```

```html
<p class="sunrise"></p>
```

Comment: i typed it in but it says its not working. what is the variable or word that i need to paste into that code:

document.querySelector(".sunrise").innerText = "Sonnenaufgang: " + sunrise;

Comment: @KaiSanjix I've added the some markup to the answer. I've used a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to add the formatted sunrise timestamp to the text content of the sunrise element. Hope it helps.

Comment: tysm it worked perfectly